# How to convert array of strings to IList<SomeType>?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to convert Datatable columns into array of Series (which I will later use to serialize them to Json), but not sure how to convert array of string to IList?  Or maybe I should use other approach? but not sure how to convert array of string to `IList<SeriesValue>`?  Or maybe I should use other approach?

```
public Series[] GetGraphData(string sp)
    {
        var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EFDbContext"].ConnectionString;
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("exec " + sp, connection))
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
            da.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Mapped);

            Series[] arrSeries = new Series[dt.Columns.Count];

            foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                if (dc.Ordinal == 0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    Series s = new Series()
                    {
                        seriesname = dc.ColumnName,
                        renderas = "Line",
                        data = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row[dc.Ordinal]).Cast<SeriesValue>().ToList()
                    };

                    arrSeries[dc.Ordinal] = s;
                }
            }

            return arrSeries;
        }
    }



 public class Series
{
    public string seriesname { get; set; }
    public string renderas { get; set; }
    public IList<SeriesValue> data { get; set; }
}

public class SeriesValue
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Json format example:

```
{
                        "seriesname": "Input",
                        "renderas": "Line",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "value": "6500"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "6500"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "6500"
                            }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated?

Comment: Just `arrSeries.ToList()`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I'm asking for.  I have a problem with this line: data = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row[dc.Ordinal]).Cast<SeriesValue>().ToList()

Comment: What's the point of SeriesValue{}, when it only contains one string?

Comment: as I need to serialize them to the specific format in Json. Question updated

Comment: As an aside, an array of strings is already an IList.
`IList list = new[] {"a", "b"};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can transform strings into objects like this:

given: strarr = array of strings

```
data = strarr.Select(o => new SeriesValue { value = o }).ToList()
```

now data is a `List<SeriesValue>`, which implements `IList<SeriesValue>`.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for